# SSH listen on 2 ports, With a single config

Tags: ssh, pam, two-factor

Im trying to make SSH logins require 2 factor auth but only on one port.

So port 1 is open only to a list of ip's managed by iptables. and only requires password / key

port 2 is open to all, But requires 2 factor auth.

Is this setup possible or would 2 sshd's need to be running

Answer (score 5):

You would need 2 sshd's to be running. I use exactly this setup on border/bastion hosts.

Comment: Here's a good article on the subject: http://www.kudos.be/multiple_sshd

Comment: yes, two seperate sshd daemons running helps with availability (accessability w/ sshd), as one will be up if the other goes down. iptables off the secondary daemon/port to only the source ips u need.